# Differentiation ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ode function defined by $x'' = t^2 - 3x′ - 2x$ and I want to figure out $x'''$. Is there any way I can solve this? Apparently the answer is $6x + 7x' + 2t - 3t^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

differentiate both sides

$x'' = t^2 - 3x' - 2x\\
x''' = 2t - 3x'' - 2x'$

Now substitute 
$x'' = t^2 - 3x' - 2x$ for $x''$ in the equation after you have differentiated.

$x''' = 2t - 3(t^2 - 3x' - 2x) - 2x'$

And simplify

$x''' = 2t - 3t^2 + 9x' + 6x - 2x'\\
x''' = 2t - 3t^2 + 7x' + 6x$